# How to use XBaseInterpreter in Xtext?

Tags: interpreter, xtext, xbase

can someone tell me, how i can use "xbaseinterpreter"? I have no idea :(

I have written a DSL used to define simple protocol-structure for a sensornet, the goal of the work is to check if a data-message(as Instance) belongs to any user-defined structure. I want to use an interpret to analyze the user-defined structure and write the corresponding information into my database directly. I thought, xbaseinterpreter is just the one i can use, but i could not find much more useful information about it.

can one use the inferred JvmModel in the interpreter?How?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

See the tortoise language as a working example of how to use xbase and the interpreter.

http://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/208_tortoise.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I have tried to execute the example, but it doesn't run, i still can not figure out, which part can invoke the interpreter.